# I have added firebase crashlytics to my react native project and play store reject my app how to fix it?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, gradle, crashlytics

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Version code 28:
SDK: Fabric io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric (consider upgrading to version com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0)
To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:

You may consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK, if available from your SDK provider or removing the SDK.
Fabric io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric: Consider upgrading to version com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0 of the SDK.

how to fix it? because I have tried multiple fixes still having the error

Answer (score 0):

- You get an error because your app uses the Fabric SDK. Google Play now requires apps to use Firebase Crashlytics instead of Fabric.
- You need to migrate from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics & Remove the Fabric SDK from your app. In your build.gradle file

  ```
  implementation 'io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.7'
  implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
  ```
- Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK to your app. In your build.gradle file &   Sync your project with the Gradle files

  ```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0'
  ```
- Follow the Firebase Crashlytics setup guide to initialize the SDK : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried it. it was rejected  and  I have completely removed crashlytics from my app, still my app is rejected same issue.    We found an issue in the following area(s):

Version code 28:
SDK: Fabric io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric (consider upgrading to version com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the same issue again and again. please check the google play console is the any old version active because this will cause the issue.
In my case there is old version code active in internal testing when ever I publish new version it's testing the old version for internal testing.

to fix --->
add the new version in all testing by doing this the old version will be deactivate.